# Convert string to double and check for errors

Tags: beginner, c, parsing, validation, floating-point

The following program converts a string to a double, and checks for errors.  It uses the `strtod()` function to do the conversion, and follows the example given for the `strtol()` function from the man page to do the error checking.

As an example, the program is executed as follows:

```
$ ./a.out 123.45
```

I would really appreciate any comments regarding the code, specifically whether there are any issues to be address or whether the code can be made more efficient or improved in any way.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *endptr, *str;
    double val;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s str\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    str = argv[1];

    errno = 0;    /* To distinguish success/failure after call */
    val = strtod(str, &endptr);

    /* Check for various possible errors */

    if ((errno == ERANGE && (val == DBL_MAX || val == -DBL_MAX))
            || (errno != 0 && val == 0.0)) {
        perror("strtod");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (endptr == str) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* If we got here, strtod() successfully parsed a number */

    printf("strtod() returned %f\n", val);

    if (*endptr != '\0')        /* Not necessarily an error... */
        printf("Further characters after number: %s\n", endptr);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Good use of `errno`, but can be improved.**

The below is decent code for detecting overflow, yet would benefit with improvements.

On overflow, the return value is `HUGE_VAL`, not necessarily `DBL_MAX`.  `HUGE_VAL` may be a large finite or an infinity.

```
if ((errno == ERANGE && (val == DBL_MAX || val == -DBL_MAX)) || ...) {
    perror("strtod");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// replace with 
if ((errno == ERANGE && (val == HUGE_VAL || val == -HUGE_VAL)) || ...) {
```

[Underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow) *may* also raise `ERANGE`.  Look at the code that attempts to discern that and review the spec.

```
if (...  || (errno != 0 && val == 0.0)) {
    perror("strtod");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

> If the result underflows ..., the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether `errno` acquires the value `ERANGE` is implementation-defined.

OP's code incorrectly assumes 0.0 on underflow.

With so  many options with 1) *if* `errno` is set and 2) what value is return, portable code nneds to fix a mess.

Portable code would use the following, yet that gives up useful conversions by some of values in the [sub-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) range `DBL_TRUE_MIN` to `DBL_MIN`.

```
if (fabs(val) < DBL_MIN) {
  if (val > 0.0) val = DBL_MIN;
  else if (val < 0.0) val = -DBL_MIN;
  // val is now, DBL_MIN, -DBL_MIN, 0.0, or -0.0

  // pedantic code would also reset errno = 0 if it changed due to `strtod()`
}
```

A somewhat less portable handing, yet retains sub-normal values - just accept any wee value.

```
if (fabs(val) < DBL_MIN) {
  // reset errno = 0 if it changed due to `strtod()`
}
```

**No conversion**

Good test for no conversion, yet some `strtod()` set `errno` in the no conversion case.  To simplify `errno` processing in the previous block, I'd recommend to do the `endptr == str` before looking at `errno`.

**Use exponential notation for output**

`"%f"` may print all values of magnitude less than 0.0000005 as `0.000000`.  This is not informative.  With large values like `DBL_MAX`, perhaps hundreds of digits are printed of which past the first 20 or so are rarely of interest.

Instead:

```
#include <float.h>

printf("strtod() returned %.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, DBL_val);
// or
printf("strtod() returned %.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, val);
```

Fancier code would assess the length of the `argv[1]` string for exponential notation and number of digits and then print out in a like-wise fashion.

**Tolerate trailing white-space**

OP code's alerts with input like "123  ", but not with "  123".  Suggest silence on trailing white-space.

```
// add
while (issapce((unsigned char) *endptr)) {
  endptr++;
}

if (*endptr != '\0')        /* Not necessarily an error... */
    printf("Further characters after number: %s\n", endptr);
```

Such non-numeric output may be best done on `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

---

Suggested alternative.

Useful as a basis for some ideas.

```
// Return status for my_strtod().
// Higher values are more problematic.
typedef enum {
  my_strtod_OK,
  my_strtod_Underflow,
  my_strtod_Overflow,
  my_strtod_ExtraJunk,
  my_strtod_NoConvertableText,
  my_strtod_N
} my_strtod_T;

// Convert a pointer to a string to double and saves its value in *dest.
// Return conversion status.
//
// `errno` is temporarily cleared by this function.  Its value on return:
//   1) Should strtod(*s, ...) set errno, then that is its value.
//   2) Otherwise errno is restored to its original value.
my_strtod_T my_strtod(double *dest, const char *s) {
  char *endptr;

  int errno_original = errno;
  errno = 0;
  *dest = strtod(s, &endptr);
  int errno_my_strtod = errno;
  if (errno == 0) {
    errno = errno_original;
  }

  if (s == endptr) {
    return my_strtod_NoConvertableText;
  }

  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr) {
    return my_strtod_ExtraJunk;
  }

  if (errno_my_strtod == ERANGE && fabs(*dest) == HUGE_VAL) {
    return my_strtod_Overflow;
  }

  if (errno_my_strtod == ERANGE && fabs(*dest) <= DBL_MIN) {
    return my_strtod_Underflow;
  }

  // Note: at this point, errno may be set
  return my_strtod_OK;
}
```

Selected C specs concerning errno:

```
/*
 * errno ...  has type int ... the value of which is set to a positive error 
 * number by several library functions.  C11dr §7.5 2 
 * 
 * errno ... is never set to zero by any library function. The value of errno
 * may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an 
 * error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of 
 * the function ... C11dr §7.5 3 
 * 
 * Of course, a library function can save the value of errno on entry and 
 * then set it to zero, as long as the original value is restored if errno’s 
 * value is still zero just before the return.  C11dr footnote 202
 */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reviewing my code. Those are all great suggestions. I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh wow, I definitely like your suggested alternative code, where `my_strtod` returns the status for each of the possibilities.  When testing for `underflow`, though, won't the test fail in some cases since `errno` may not necessary be set to `ERANGE` in some implementations, as you indicated earlier?

Comment: @Domenic [won't the test fail](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199775/convert-string-to-double-and-check-for-errors/199780?noredirect=1#comment384660_199780) --> depends on what is "failure" and the coding goal in this case.  In practice, conversion to a |value| less than `DBL_MIN` is simply a tolerable non-failure result - regardless of `errno`.  Portable code could use `if (fabs(val) < DBL_MIN) {
  if (val > 0.0) val = DBL_MIN;
  else if (val < 0.0) val = -DBL_MIN;
  return my_strtod_Underflow; }`

Comment: @Domenic Too be clear, in the cases of `fabs(y) <= DBL_MIN`,  there is too much left to implementation defined behavior for super portable code.  This all gets very messy once one considers that `strod()` is subject to different results based on rounding modes (5 of them).  Do the best you can and document your expectations.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks again for all your help.  Cheers!

Comment: I think it's better to use `fpclassify(val) == FP_SUBNORMAL` than `fabs(val) < DBL_MIN` - it's much more explicit about intent, likely to be more efficient (some operations are notoriously slow with subnormals; I'm not sure whether `fabs()` and `<` are among them), and demonstrably correct.  It acts as if overloaded overloaded, so no need to match a macro constant to the type of `val`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Although speed concerns are useful, the time spent `fpclassify(val) == FP_SUBNORMAL` or `fabs(val) < DBL_MIN` or like code  is certainly at least an order of magnitude less than the `strtod()` call itself.

Comment: @TobySpeight The classify functions have their own implementation defined behavior too. I would not say they are overloaded, for example like C++ function can be.  `fpclassify(val)` converts `val` to a _semantic type_ which could be a floating point type of narrower range than `val`. The change of type renders compare to  `FP_SUBNORMAL` of questionable portable usefulness. See C11 footnote 231.

Comment: Actually, I *did* write "**as if** overloaded" - and I guess that's why it has to be a macro and not a function as it is in C++.

Comment: @TobySpeight _semantic type_ is from the C spec.  I too an unsure what the C spec is really trying to do here with _semantic type_.  _semantic type_ and other spec verbiage about the classify functions sound like weasel words to me.  End result, the classify functions, IMO, are broken.  They _should_ have been spec'd overloaded (perhaps through `_Generic`) and render a result **without** type change.  `signbit()` seems an OK exception though as it does not have a "First, an argument represented in a format wider than its
semantic type is converted to its semantic type." step.

Comment: I've now [asked about this](//stackoverflow.com/q/51443298) over on SO.

Comment: @TobySpeight I hope that question remains open for some time- it serves a very good answer.